# Android display apps on screen device

Tags: android, screen, swipe, homescreen, flipboard

i want to create apps to display beside home screen, if position home screen and then swipe right display own apps, anybody give me solution to create that.

Below example apps what i want

**there 3 screen, when left screen swipe display own apps screen**

[image]

or like flipboard on Samsung Galaxy S6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can achieve that without writing your own launcher aka homescreen. The reason google now is integrated is because that is the homescreen launcher that Google developed (and similarly on HTC they have developed their own homescreen and added some sort of extra screen similar to Google Now)

Comment: i have tried to create own louncher with reference this link http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/

but, i don't know how to create louncher who display multiple page like google, google louncher have multi page, left screen "google now", main screen "home screen like example", and right screen is another apps icon, can you have solution about that ? thanks

Comment: Look into ViewPager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) which allows you to create swipe-able pages. It doesn't sound like you understand the intricacies of creating your own launcher though.

Comment: thanks about your answer, but my goal is to make like a flipboard on samsung galaxy note 4, when swipe right display flipboard